# How to calculate the total amount for similar keys in PHP using Laravel eloquent/collections

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I currently have the below json response that the API is returning. I am able to return it using Laravel Eloquent. There are several users and each user has a several receipts. A receipt has types and status. I want to try to get the total sum amount for each receipt that is related to its type and status. I was able to return the below json response using

```
$this->user->with('receipts')->has('receipts')->get(['id', 'name']);
```

I have tried using multiple laravel collections methods https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods
But I am still unable to get the desired response.

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "kent",
        "receipts": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 1,
                "type_id": 1,
                "status": 0,
                "amount": 100
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "user_id": 1,
                "type_id": 1,
                "status": 0,
                "amount": 100
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "user_id": 1,
                "type_id": 2,
                "status": 1,
                "amount": 50
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "user_id": 1,
                "type_id": 2,
                "status": 0,
                "amount": 30
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "user_id": 1,
                "type_id": 2,
                "status": 0,
                "amount": 30
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "user_id": 1,
                "type_id": 1,
                "status": 0,
                "amount": 20
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "user_id": 1,
                "type_id": 1,
                "status": 1,
                "amount": 10
            }
        ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "allison",
            "receipts": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "user_id": 2,
                    "type_id": 1,
                    "status": 0,
                    "amount": 20
                }
        ]
    }
]
```

I expect to get the below

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "kent",
        "receipts": [
            {
                "performance and deleted": 220,
                "performance and not deleted": 10,
                "project and deleted": 60,
                "project and deleted": 50
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "allison",
        "receipts": [
            {
                "performance and deleted": 20,
                "performance and not deleted": 0,
                "project and deleted": 0,
                "project and not deleted": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the sum of amount with

```
$this->user->with(['receipts' => function($query) {
    $query->selectRaw("SUM(amount) as amount, type_id, status, user_id")->groupBy('type_id', 'status', 'user_id');
}])->has('receipts')->get(['id', 'name']);
```

You can use collection methods to get the desired output

```
$this->user->with(['receipts' => function($query) {
    $query->selectRaw("SUM(amount) as amount, type_id, status, user_id")->groupBy('type_id', 'status', 'user_id');
}])->has('receipts')->get(['id', 'name'])
->each(function ($user) {
    $user->setRelation(
        'receipts',
        $user->receipts->mapWithKeys(function ($receipt) {
            return [
                $receipt->type_id . ' and ' . $receipt->status => $receipt->amount // format the key as you wish
            ];
        })
    );
})
```

Comment: I tried it however, this is what I'm getting, an empty array of receipts

`[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "kent",
        "receipts": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "allison",
        "receipts": []
    }
]`

Comment: @CEJ See the updated answer. Need to add the foreign key to the select statement as well.

Comment: How will I be able to populate it like the expected answer? This does group the types and statuses

Comment: You mean you need the keys like `type_id1 and status0`

Comment: Yes I need the keys like `admin status": 220` `user status": 10` `superadmin status":60 `

Comment: The key would be something like any text that I want to map to

Comment: Kindly check the updated expected answer. This is what I expect

Comment: See the updated answer. You have to use collection methods to get desired output. I've used the `type_id` and `status` to generate the key.

Comment: Thank you!! Best answer definitely!! Last question sorry to be a bug, How will I be able to get the expected answer? Should I be using filter method?

Comment: Expected result as in to show the ones that have a sum of amount of 0 as well

Comment: I tried it and I currently get this `[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "kent",
"receipts": {
"1 and 0": 220,
"1 and 1": 10,
"2 and 1": 60,
"2 and 0": 50
}
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "allison",
"receipts": {
"1 and 0": 20,
}
}
]`

Comment: It does not currently show the "1 and 1" and "2 and 1" and "2 and 0" in the second id. It should show them as total 0

Comment: It might be because of  `has('receipts')` . Remove it and try.

Comment: So type_id is an array that has 2 items and status is an array of 2 items. Should I manually write them and manually map them? If so how will I be able to achieve the desired results?

Comment: Any idea on how to display the expected result?

Comment: if you have a collection of `statuses` and `types` with name attribute in each you can do `$types->firstWhere($receipt->type_id)->name . ' and ' . $statuses->firstWhere('id', $receipt->status)->name`

Answer (score 0):

You may use foreach and other loops to make the json you want!
use This function to convert your collection to the json you want :

```
public function convert(Collection $collection) 
{
    $result_collection = $collection;
    $payment_collections = [];
    foreach ($result_collection->receipts as $receipt)
    {
        $payment["type_id${receipt->type_id} and status${$receipt->status}"] = $receipt->amount;
    }
    $result_collection->receipts = $payment_collections;
    return $result_collection;
}
```

> And This is same way to get total amount. Just put an foreach and add each amount to a variable that initialized with 0;

and there is other ways like change toArray function in your **Resource Collection**.

Comment: I am getting Property [receipts] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the script assuming your data is a PHP array so you may change some part of my code.
For example you may change:

```
$row['receipts']
// To 
$row->receipts
```

anyway

```
// The function in your controller
function index(){
  $users=User::whereHas('receipts')->with('receipts')->get()->toArray();
  return convert($users);
}
// The helper function 
function convert($data){
  $data=collect($data);
$allTypes=[];
$allStatuses=[];
return $data->each(function($row) use (&$allTypes,&$allStatuses){
    $types=collect($row['receipts'])->pluck('type_id')->toArray();
    $statuses=collect($row['receipts'])->pluck('status')->toArray();
    $allTypes=array_unique(array_merge($allTypes,$types));
    $allStatuses=array_unique(array_merge($allStatuses,$statuses));
})->map(function ($row,$index) use (&$allTypes,&$allStatuses){
    $result=[];
    $receipts=collect($row['receipts']);
    foreach ($allTypes as $type){
        foreach ($allStatuses as $status){
            $result["type_id {$type} and status {$status}: "]=$receipts->where('type_id',$type)->where('status',$status)->sum('amount');
        }
    }
    $row['receipts']=$result;
    return $row;
});
}
```

[image]

Comment: Read what I wrote you may change some part of the code, I tested it and it worked like charm, and I uploaded the screen shot of the result

Comment: Or if you don't want to change my code you can parse the DB result to array using ->get()->toArray(); then pass it to the function which I've written.

Comment: I edited the code and showed you how to fetch your users first check it again

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Is there a way to only use collection methods and not the foreach loops. Making it simpler

Comment: Kindly check the updated expected answer. This is what I expect

Comment: I changed the code and I tried to use Laravel collection methods as possible as I could.

Comment: :)) I did what you had wanted and now you changed your expectation. I was here to solve your problem and I did; not here to build your whole project. Good luck my friend.

Comment: not really... the thing was that there was a misunderstanding, since you thought that the status and type id are the keys and values. I actually am looking for a string

Comment: It's not so hard you can get all types from DB using $allTypes variable and replace their title instead of their id.

Comment: This is why I had to update the answer to not have any misunderstanding on what answer I expect